# Blob is not a Valid UTF-8 String - Only after "–"

Tags: data, string, static-resources, data-types, parser

I created a CSV parser that parses CSV's from static resources.

I am returned with a `Blob is not a Valid UTF-8 String` error when parsing the character: "–" different from "-". The "–" is apparently still a unicode character: 
https://unicodelookup.com/#%E2%80%93/1.

The sheet is being saved as UTF-8 CSV and the data was exporting from Salesforce using data loader 38.0.

Can someone explain why this character is returning the `Blob is not a Valid UTF-8 String` ***even though the character appears to be a UTF-8 character?***

**CSV:**

[image]

**HEX with bad character:**

```
00:00:00:XXX USER_DEBUG [XX]|DEBUG|4f626a6563742c437573746f6d5f446563696d616c5f5f632c437573746f6d5f5f632c42726f6b656e5f4669656c645f5f630d0a4d794f746865724f626a6563745f5f632c312c412c5858209620546869732068797068656e206973206275737465640d0a
```

**HEX without bad character:**

```
00:00:00:XXX USER_DEBUG [XX]|DEBUG|4f626a6563742c437573746f6d5f446563696d616c5f5f632c437573746f6d5f5f632c42726f6b656e5f4669656c645f5f630d0a4d794f746865724f626a6563745f5f632c312c412c58582020546869732068797068656e206973206275737465640d0a
```

***||||||Update:***

Upon opening the file in Notepad, it appears the file was encoded in ANSI, even though excel states the file is encoding in UTF-8 when I open it. After saving at UTF-8 in Notepad, that resolved the symbol issue.

**This did not work:**

[image]

**This did:**

[image]

With this being said are there any capabilities within the blob class or another class to convert the file from ANSI to UTF-8 within Salesforce as opposed to relying on customers to ensure the file is in the correct encoding?

Comment: We would need to see a hex dump of the file. Maybe there's a BOM (Byte Order Mark), or maybe it's an invalid UTF-8 encoding (i.e. it's actually encoded in a different code page/encoding). Perhaps you could encode an example with uuencode? This would help us narrow it down. Or even a simple script: `System.debug(EncodingUtil.convertTohex(resource.body));`

Comment: @sfdcfox I have added the Hex values and the CSV table data above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, yes, the offending byte was 0x96, instead of whatever it should have been in UTF-8. There's no good way to fix that, as most methods only support UTF-8. You may try a combination of EncodingUtil.convertToHex/String.replace/EncodingUtil.urlDecode to try and get it from ASCII/ANSI to UTF-8, but you'll have to guess the encoding, which would be non-trivial. It's probably just better to catch the exception and advise the user to obtain help with getting the correct encoding.